# Error envio de put en Angular

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, angular, callback

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en angular y llega un momento que al realizar una llamada put a la base de datos, no me la realiza. Este error no se a que se debe puesto que anteriormente la realizaba perfectamente. Si hago esta misma llamada en otro servicio diferente si funciona, pero me gustaría hacerla en ese servicio. He probado a eliminar el servicio y crear uno exactamente igual pero no me ha dado resultado.

```
modificar(nombreUsuario, idObjeto, equipado){
    const body = {};
    const urlmod = this.objetosUsuarioURL + '/?nombreUsuario='+ nombreUsuario  + '&idObjeto=' + idObjeto + '&equipado=' + equipado;
    console.log(urlmod);
    return this.http.put(urlmod, body);
  }
```

Por pantalla me saca la url bien:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero en el apartado network no aparece la llamada por ninguna parte.
Si envío esta url a través de un programa como Postman me devuelve true y realiza el cambio.

Comment: seguro que no tendras puesto algun filtro en la tab network? Por que si te hace el `console.log` quiere decir que la funciona se llama

Comment: No tengo ningún filtro, no se llega a realizar el update

Comment: ¿Podrías poner todo el mensaje de error? Y sin que sea una imagen, se hace más sencillo de leer si es texto. Gracias.

Comment: El problema es que no da ningún mensaje de error, lo que muestro en la imagen es la dirección que se debería enviar mediante el put, pero que no la hace. Esa misma es la que cojo luego para comprobar en el Postman y funciona todo correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

#### ESTA RESPUESTA ESTA INCOMPLETA. ESPERO RETROALIMENTACION PARA PODER SEGUIR AYUDANDO CON EL PROBLEMA.

Generalmente el objeto que mandas en el segundo parámetro no debería estar vacío. Al desconocer tu backend no puedo asegurar que tu problema este en el.

Para capturar los errores y trabajar con tu respuesta antes de retornarla desde el servicio puedes usar esta estructura:

```js
modificar(nombreUsuario, idObjeto, equipado){
    const body = {};
    const urlmod = this.objetosUsuarioURL + '/?nombreUsuario='+ nombreUsuario  + '&idObjeto=' + idObjeto + '&equipado=' + equipado;
    console.log(urlmod);
    return this.http.put(urlmod, body).pipe(
        map((respuesta:any)=>{
           //En esta seccion agregar logica extra para trabajar con tus datos
           //Pongo esto para debugueo
           console.log('respuesta', respuesta)

           return respuesta

        }),
        catchError(error=>{
            //En esta parte capturamos errores que se generen en el backend
            console.log(error)
            //trhowError genera un error para que sea compatible con rxjs. 
            return trhowError(error)
        })
    )
  }
```

Estas serían las importaciones que necesitas:

```
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError, Observable } from 'rxjs'
```

Creo que de esta manera encontraras más fácilmente el problema.

Comment: Hola, he probado a añadir la captura de errores, pero sigue sin devolver nada, es como si el método put no se llegase a efectuar. Yo creo que debe de ser algún problema relacionado con el servidor puesto que antes funcionaba correctamente.

Comment: Que te muestra el `console.log('respuesta', respuesta`? Dentro del `map`.

Comment: Extrañamente, al iniciar el servidor de nuevo esta tarde ha vuelto a funcionar con total normalidad. Igual que se fue, volvió. Gracias por tu atención igualmente :)

Comment: Es más común de lo que crees. Que bueno que se arreglo.